# How to convert a 3D array directly to a video in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video, rgb

I have a 3D matrix with a dimension of `600x600x28` which the last index is the number of frames and want to convert it to a video file. As you can see in the code below I convert the array into a 4D matrix with the size of `600X600X3X28` to make it compatible with WriteVideo format. but I am not sure why the output video is empty!

```
Orig = randi([1 1000],600,600,28);

x = uint8(255 * mat2gray(Orig));
map=jet;

for i=1:size(x,3)
x_all(:,:,:,i) = ind2rgb(x(:,:,i),map);
end

x_all = uint8(x_all);
v = VideoWriter('myvideo');
open(v);
writeVideo(v,x_all);
close(v)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to convert the video to RGB, you may create a Grayscale video.

Example:

```
x = randi([0, 255], 600, 600, 28, 'uint8');
v = VideoWriter('myvideo_grayscale.avi', 'Grayscale AVI');
open(v);
writeVideo(v, x);
close(v)
```

---

The reason you are getting a black video is that `ind2rgb` returns values in range [0, 1] and when converting to `uint8`: `x_all = uint8(x_all);`, all the values are `0`s and `1`s (instead of range [0, 255]).

Example for creating colored video:

```
Orig = randi([1 1000],600,600,28);

x = im2uint8(mat2gray(Orig));

map = jet(256); % Use colormap with 256 colors (the default is 64).

x_all = zeros(size(x, 1), size(x, 2), 3, size(x, 3), 'uint8'); % Allocate space

for i=1:size(x,3)
    x_all(:,:,:,i) = im2uint8(ind2rgb(x(:,:,i), map));
end

v = VideoWriter('myvideo.avi');
open(v);
writeVideo(v,x_all);
close(v)
```

---

In case you are actually getting an empty video file (not just black video), something is wrong with your setup.

Comment: Thanks for a comprehensive answer. when I am using im2unit color distribution of some frames is different from the original images which are single precision. Therefore, I used im2single instead of im2unit but all the frames in a video are dark which means zero.