# How to make a colored video with im2single instead of im2uint in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, video, rgb

The code below makes a video from `600x600x28` matrix using im2unit8 but in some of the frames like the below image, the color distribution is different from the original one. This happened due to the use of `im2uint8`.

I tried to use `im2single` to address the issue but since it maps the matrix between 0 and 1 the video frames are all black. I am wondering is there any way to make a colored video with  `im2single` function.

```
Orig = randi([1 1000],600,600,28);
x = im2uint8(mat2gray(Orig));
% x = im2single(mat2gray(Orig));

map = jet(256); % Use colormap with 256 colors (the default is 64).

x_all = zeros(size(x, 1), size(x, 2), 3, size(x, 3), 'uint8'); % Allocate space

for i=1:size(x,3)
    x_all(:,:,:,i) = im2uint8(ind2rgb(x(:,:,i), map));
end

v = VideoWriter('1_3.avi');
v.FrameRate = 1;
open(v);
writeVideo(v,x_all);
close(v)
```

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzPVK.jpg)

[converted image by uint8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1d8V4.jpg)

Comment: It feels like this should have been an edit to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68565058/how-to-convert-a-3d-array-directly-to-a-video-in-matlab) - since it's asking the same thing but as if the answer which you marked as accepted wasn't actually a solution to your problem...

Comment: **1.** Replace: `x_all = zeros(size(x, 1), size(x, 2), 3, size(x, 3), 'uint8');` with `x_all = zeros(size(x, 1), size(x, 2), 3, size(x, 3), 'single');` **2.** Replace `x_all(:,:,:,i) = im2uint8(ind2rgb(x(:,:,i), map));` with `x_all(:,:,:,i) = im2single(ind2rgb(x(:,:,i), map));`

Comment: The issue still exists and surprisingly some of the frames in the video are dark! however, the original frame is colored.